# Fatal error: Class 'JApplicationHelper' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\cms\application\cms.php on line 633

Tags: php, joomla, fatal-error

I have gotten the following error when I have tried editing my `joomla` page. I am still in development mode and have not uploaded it to my site yet. The error is as follows:

> Fatal error: Class 'JApplicationHelper' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\cms\application\cms.php on line 633

However, when I go to that line in my code the only code around it is as follows:

```
/**
 * Is admin interface?
 *
 * @return  boolean  True if this application is administrator.
 *
 * @since   3.2
 */
public function isAdmin()
{
    return ($this->getClientId() === 1);
}
```

All of the references in the PHP code to 'JApplicationHelper' are on lines 679-690 and are as follows:

```
    // Generate a session name.
    $name = JApplicationHelper::getHash($this->get('session_name', get_class($this)));

    // Calculate the session lifetime.
    $lifetime = (($this->get('lifetime')) ? $this->get('lifetime') * 60 : 900);

    // Initialize the options for JSession.
    $options = array(
        'name'   => $name,
        'expire' => $lifetime
    );
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which line is 633 in the file: `cms.php`?

Comment: line 633 is: * @return  boolean  True if this application is administrator.

Comment: Basically JApplicationHelper has not been instantiated or has not been made available to this scope of your PHP code. It is near impossible to tell you what's going on because we are blind as to whether or not `$name = JApplicationHelper::getHash` is contained within a controller, include, etc... Do not post all umpteen million lines of your code but just enough to give us an idea of your scope.

Comment: I think you should be able to use `var_dump();` right before the `JApplicationHelper` call and it should show you what is available to you.

Comment: My line numbering program was off... Line 633 is:  $name = JApplicationHelper::getHash($this->get('session_name', get_class($this)));

Answer (score 0):

Before your class declaration, import the JApplicationHelper file:

```
jimport('joomla.application.helper');
```

Comment: As my name suggest, I am a loser when it comes to this. So, exactly where would I put that?

Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you modifying cms.php or are you working on your own custom file?

Comment: You can try adding that import line directly before the class declaration at the top of the page: class JApplicationCms extends JApplicationWeb {, but modifying the core files is going down the wrong road. You won't be able to update Joomla and it's likely you'll break other core functionality.

Comment: What would you suggest then? backup my database and do a fresh install of xampp?

Comment: If you're not attempting to modify cms.php, but getting this error, I would try doing a fresh install of Joomla or reverting cms.php to its original contents. If you're trying to modify cms.php to do some additional functionality, then I'd recommend looking into building a custom extension instead of modifying core files.

Comment: Thank you, I am not trying to do anything custom. I just came back to work with that error. The fresh install didn't fix the problem. I am at a loss of what to do now...